# Streaming pubsub -bigtable using apache beam dataflow java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-bigtable

Trying to update the pubsub json message to bigtable .I am running code from local machine .the dataflow job is getting created .but i dont see any data updated in bigtable instance and also it does not throw any error in console or dataflow job.I also tried to have hardcode value and try to update in bigtable but still it didnt work. Please can anyone suggest or guide me in this issue

```
 try{
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(projectArgs).create();
    options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
    System.out.println("tempfile-" + options.getTempLocation());
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    System.out.println("options" + options.getTempLocation());
    p.apply("Read PubSub Messages", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION))
            .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new RowGenerator())).apply(CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable(bigtableConfig));

    p.run();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {

```
try {
System.out.println("In for RowGenerator");
String decodedMessageAsJsonString = context.element();
System.out.println("decodedMessageAsJsonString"+decodedMessageAsJsonString);

String rowKey = String.valueOf(
        LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneId.of("UTC"))
                .toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC));
System.out.println("rowKey"+rowKey);

Put put = new Put(rowKey.getBytes());
put.addColumn("VALUE".getBytes(), "VALUE".getBytes(), decodedMessageAsJsonString.getBytes());
     // put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("IBS"), Bytes.toBytes("name"),Bytes.toBytes("ram"));

context.output(put);
}catch (Throwable e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcqxD.png)

Comment: It seems like you were doing great, no error log was shown. So I would suggest you that debug step by step. First of all, I would just print out JSON messages from pubsub, second, I would create a sample JSON to upload to Bigtable. If both do work, then I would just combine two codes. Also, I would look at some simple template from [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates).

Comment: Actually i tired doing the debug thing but it is getting stuck at p.apply("Read PubSub Messages", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION)) i waited for more than 1 hr ..but didnt got any output .Thankyou for the help will try in that way .If you have any other suggestion please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with the Bigtable side of the template. Just make sure that the column family (which I am assuming is "VALUE" exists on the destination table.

Are you sure that you are reading the right PubSub subscription and there are messages being sent to PubSub. If its all correct, it seems there is some issue in the PubSub configuration. Maybe add the PubSub tag on the question and someone from the pubsub community can help.

Comment: projects/nameofproject/topics/nameoftopic -this topic name which i am passing
and the message published in json format e.g { "emp_id": 41, "salary": 27000, "dept_name": "development", "ts_created": 1648019144992, "emp_name": "zoya"} -thankyou for your help